# nginx rewrite specific sub domains

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, wordpress, rewrite

---

I am trying to rerwrite any sub domains outside of an approved list i.e.  (dev,test,home).domain.com

here is what I am working with now:

```
#rewrite all sub domains
 if ($host ~* "^([^.]+(\.[^.]+)*)\.domain.com$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://domain.com$1 permanent;
        break;
    }
```

the problem is it rewrites all sub domains.  I have a solution in apache but I am having issues converting it. apache version:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(dev|test|local\.blog)\.domain\.me$ [NC]`

Updates:

```
server {
    listen 80;
  server_name *.domain.com domain.com;
  root /srv/www/www.domain.com;
  access_log /srv/logs/www_domain.com.access;
  error_log /srv/logs/www_domain.com.error error;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error.htm;
  location  /error.htm {
    internal;
  }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  # remove all sub domains and www
  if ($host !~* (dev|test|prod)\.domain\.com) {
            rewrite ^ http://domain.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  location / {
    index index.html index.php index.htm;
    location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
      include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
  }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # serve favicon
  location = /favicon.ico { 
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # process robots.txt
  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # serve static files directly
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # block access to .ht files
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # short cuts
    if ($uri ~* "/login") {
        rewrite ^/login(/.*)? /wp-admin$1;
    }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css application/x-javascript text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain    text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
    location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
            expires 31536000s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.3";
    }
    location ~ \.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
            expires 180s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=180, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.3";
    }
    location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
            expires 31536000s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.3";
    }
    # END W3TC Browser Cache
    # BEGIN W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
    if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
    }
    if (-d $request_filename) {
            break;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ "(robots\.txt|sitemap(_index|[0-9]+)?\.xml(\.gz)?)") {
            break;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* \.(css|js|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$) {
            return 404;
    }
    # END W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on @AlexD reply I have updated my solution.  if you have any other suggestions fellow geeks, let me know.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.noconformity.co;
  rewrite ^ http://noconformity.co$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name noconformity.co ~(sub1|sub2)\.noconformity\.co$;
  root /srv/www/www.noconformity.co;
  access_log /var/log/nginx-hosts/www_noconformity.co.access;
  error_log /var/log/nginx-hosts/www_noconformity.co.error error;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error.htm;
  location  /error.htm {
    internal;
  }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  location / {
    index index.html index.php index.htm;
    location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
      include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
  }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # serve favicon
  location = /favicon.ico { 
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # process robots.txt
  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # serve static files directly
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # block access to .ht files
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # short cuts
    if ($uri ~* "/login") {
        rewrite ^/login(/.*)? /wp-admin$1;
    }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css application/x-javascript text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
    location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
            expires 31536000s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.3";
    }
    location ~ \.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
            expires 180s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=180, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.3";
    }
    location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
            expires 31536000s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.3";
    }
    # END W3TC Browser Cache
    # BEGIN W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
    if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
    }
    if (-d $request_filename) {
            break;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ "(robots\.txt|sitemap(_index|[0-9]+)?\.xml(\.gz)?)") {
            break;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* \.(css|js|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$) {
            return 404;
    }
    # END W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

this is the default website:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name localhost;
  root /srv/www/www.default.site;
  access_log /var/log/nginx-hosts/default.access;
  error_log /var/log/nginx-hosts/default.error error;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error.htm;
  location  /error.htm {
    internal;
  }

  location / {
    index index.html index.php index.htm;
    location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
        if (!-f $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name){
            return 404;
      }
      include        fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) how to convert apache rewrite rules to nginx.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name domain.com ~(dev|test|local)\.domain\.com$;

  # ... your rules here ... 

}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name *.domain.com;
  rewrite ^ http://domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: check out the answer I just posted which works correctly, do you have any recommendations to perfect it further? thank you for your help bro.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you must use [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.domain.com;
    ...

    if ($host ~* (?<!(dev|test|local))\.domain\.com) {
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com$request_uri permanent;
    }

}
```

Comment: ok, now I am getting infinite redirect errors. I will make some edits above

Comment: Put the `domain.com` into a separate `server` context.

Comment: hmmmm...not sure if I can do that, I have an entire grouping of other rules nested inside of the same server command, i would have to duplicate all of those right?

Comment: ok, i just added the full code sample, thoughts?

Comment: i found the solution, but will have to wait 6 hours to post it

Comment: Please check out my updated answer.

Comment: check out the answer I just posted which works correctly, do you have any recommendations to perfect it further? thank you for your help bro.

Comment: I tried your reply and it didn't work, the only solution I could get to work was using ifs.  any ideas for improvement? btw, the primary domain is domain.com with no prefix

Answer (score 0):

after locating a killer tool : http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/ I was able to rebuild my nginx vhost config to work correctly, however, I am open to suggestions  , modifications.  This is a multi host server, and individual host file in sites-available for each host

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name *.domain.com domain.com;
  root /srv/www/www.domain.com;
  access_log /srv/logs/www_domain.com.access;
  error_log /srv/logs/www_domain.com.error error;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error.htm;
  location  /error.htm {
    internal;
  }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(dev|test|prod)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  # all sub domains and www
    if ($http_host !~* "^(dev|test|prod)\.domain\.com$"){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    }
    if ($http_host ~ "^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$"){
        set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
    }
    if ($rule_0 = "21"){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 permanent;
        break;
    }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  location / {
    index index.html index.php index.htm;
    location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
      include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
  }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # serve favicon
  location = /favicon.ico { 
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # process robots.txt
  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # serve static files directly
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # block access to .ht files
  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
  }
  # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # short cuts
    if ($uri ~* "/login") {
        rewrite ^/login(/.*)? /wp-admin$1;
    }
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/css application/x-javascript text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon;
    location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
            expires 31536000s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.3";
    }
    location ~ \.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml)$ {
            expires 180s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=180, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.3";
    }
    location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
            expires 31536000s;
            add_header Pragma "public";
            add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
            add_header X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.3";
    }
    # END W3TC Browser Cache
    # BEGIN W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
    if (-f $request_filename) {
            break;
    }
    if (-d $request_filename) {
            break;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~ "(robots\.txt|sitemap(_index|[0-9]+)?\.xml(\.gz)?)") {
            break;
    }
    if ($request_uri ~* \.(css|js|html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|swf|tar|tif|tiff|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$) {
            return 404;
    }
    # END W3TC Skip 404 error handling by WordPress for static files
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

default server configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80 default;
  server_name localhost;
  root /srv/www/www.default.site;
  access_log /srv/logs/localhost.access;
  error_log /srv/logs/localhost.error error;

  error_page 400 401 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error.htm;
  location  /error.htm {
    internal;
  }

  location / {
    index index.html index.php index.htm;
    location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
        if (!-f $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name){
            return 404;
      }
      include        fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check link to nginx documentation I provided above. Using if's to select http_host "is a wrong, cumbersome, and ineffective way" (quote from documentation). Also check http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: thank you for sending me the site, i was there way before posting to this thread.  as stated this is a multi host server so your solution will not work as many domains hit this box, in apache it would be 1 vhost per site with .htaccess rules.  so... I have to use 1 file from what i can see.  can you post an extended solution using what I have provided? is that possible.  I read that using "if" is not ideal, but it works correctly.

Comment: Please, read documentation for nginx `listen` and `server_name` directives http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name. My solution will work with same set of domain names as yours: `*.domain.com` and `domain.com`. And it uses one configuration file.

Comment: If you want to use multiple 2nd level domains like domain.com, domain2.com etc, all you need is to remove `default_server` option from `listen` directive or add another `server { }` block with `listen 80 default_server` and `server_name _`.

Comment: @Alex I added my default host configuration. this box hosts 1-x sites, right now this default captures all domains not enabled.  all of the other active domains have their own hosts file like the solution posted.  do you think this has been setup correctly? I am new to nginx so this process has really helped me.

Comment: `default` option for `listen` is deprecated since version 0.8.21, you should use `default_server` instead. And, as I said before, using `if`'s to select by `$host_header` is not correct approach. Using `if`'s to check file/directory existence also incorrect, there is `try_files` directive for that.

Comment: so if I change the default to default_server, how would you recommend adjusting the if blocks? I keep trying these variations and they do not seem to work.  can you post an example using the solution here that currently works?  by chance? thank you for your time.

Comment: In your case you could simply delete all you `if`s and their content (half of them won't have any effect anyway) and copy remaining statements to [... you rules here ... ] mark in my answer. Also most locations starting after comment `# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache` won't match anything too because of earlier location with comment `serve static files directly`.

Comment: @AlexD ok, I have made all the changes you requested, works great.  any other pointers?  I am a noob too nginx, sorry to ask so many questions.